# How to reset zoom for UIWebView in IOS

Tags: ios, uiwebview, uipinchgesturerecognizer

I have an `UIWebView` with `scalesPageToFit = YES` and `contentMode = UIViewContentModeScaleToFill` and it zooms automatically to fit my `UIWebView` size after page loads.

I can zoom in with pinch gesture but then I cannot reset the zoom by code to it's initial state (just after `webViewDidFinishLoad`).

The only solution I found was to reload the uiwebview but i don't want it.

Any suggestions?

**EDIT**

I can make it work like this

```
  [self.webView.scrollView zoomToRect:CGRectMake(0, 0, self.webView.scrollView.contentSize.width, self.webView.scrollView.contentSize.height) animated:YES];
    CGPoint top = CGPointMake(0, 0);
    [self.webView.scrollView setContentOffset:top animated:YES];
```

but I need to know how long does these animations take...with `animated:NO` it does not work

Answer (score 1):

Try this to zoom in/out webview

```
 webView.scrollView.zoomScale = 1;
```